# Showing transition density for Brownian motion satisfies the heat equation

Tags: probability, partial-differential-equations

Let $B$ be a Brownian motion in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $U$ be a (sufficiently regular) open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Let $\tau_U$ be the time $B$ exits $U$. Let $D_\epsilon(y)$ denote the ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $y$, and let

$$p(t,x,y) = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \epsilon^{-n} \mathbb P^x(B_t \in D_\epsilon(y);t<\tau_U) .$$

I am trying to show that $p(t,x,y)$ satisfies the heat equation

$$\frac{d}{dt} p(t,x,y) = \frac12 \Delta_y p(t,x,y).$$

Intuitively, when $s$ is small, $\mathbb P^x(B_{t+s} \in D_\epsilon(y);t+s<\tau_U) - \mathbb P^x(B_t \in D_\epsilon(y);t<\tau_U)$ should be approximately equal to $\mathbb P^x(B_{t+s} \in D_\epsilon(y)) - \mathbb P^x(B_t \in D_\epsilon(y))$. If we divide this by $s \epsilon^n$ and let $s,\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, we get (up to a factor of a power of $2\pi$) the derivative in $t$ of the density of the normal distribution, which we know satisfies the heat equation. But how can I make this intuition precise?